# Why SQL Server CTE with TOP limit is slower than non-limited

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, database-performance

I trying to find out performance between paging methods which use SQL Server 2008. I have use flowing query:

```
WITH CTE(RowNo, UniqueId)
AS (
    SELECT TOP (5000+100) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReceiveDate) AS RowNo, UniqueId
    FROM LogEntries
    WHERE ServerId = '111.112.113.114'
)
SELECT 
    TOP 100 CTE.RowNo, CTE.UniqueId, L.[Subject]
    FROM
        CTE
        INNER JOIN LogEntries L ON L.UniqueId = CTE.UniqueId
    WHERE
        CTE.RowNo > 5000;
```

The **Server Statistics** report SQL Server took 232ms to complete the query. But when I remove **TOP (5000+100)**, the job done half faster (just 135ms). I had tried repeatly number times, result as the same.

The table LogEntries has 12Mi rows / 3.3 GB size.

Any reason for limited result set run slower than full result?

**After some suggest from SO'guys, with created the index on ReceiveDate (include ServerId) below is my fasted query, it took ~36ms without any extra ORDER BY required:**

```
WITH CTE(RowNo, UniqueId)
AS (
    SELECT TOP 5100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReceiveDate) AS RowNo, UniqueId
    FROM LogEntries
    WHERE ServerId = '111.112.113.114'
)
SELECT 
    CTE.RowNo, CTE.UniqueId, L.[Subject]
    FROM
        CTE
        LEFT JOIN LogEntries L ON L.UniqueId = CTE.UniqueId
    WHERE
        CTE.RowNo > 5000
```

Comment: I'd advice you to check the the execution plans for both of those queries, because it should clearly show why. But generally speaking - TOP is expensive due to sorting

Comment: Execute DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS before running those queries, in order to be sure one of them is not getting data from cache.

Comment: Tell us more about indexes you have on this table.

Comment: Did you consider to have a clustered index on ReceivedDate column?

Comment: Your first query doesn't have an `ORDER BY` clause anyway so it is completely unguaranteed what `5100` rows it returns. The application of `TOP` probably changes the execution plan anyway though. e.g. it may use a different index or join type.

Comment: My tables indexes: UniqueId (INT, Clustered). I have created ReceivedDate (include ServerId), remove all TOP clause, use CTE.RowNo BETWEEN 5000 AND 5100. Now execution time reduced to ~80ms. It's very good?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are already doing a row_number which require and order by on your sub result's table.

Like suggested, check the execution plan.

And you're top 5000 + 100 is redundant with your cte.rowno > 5000. Try cte.rowno between 5000 and 5100.

Comment: in the "older" days there was a trick with paging where you selected top twice to minimize the selections for the paging. I suspect it's the same pattern reused with the newer "common table expression".